# How do I set up Basic Routing in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am trying to understand how very basic routing works in Angular 2 from the [docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#base-href) and I don't get it.

I set up a [PLUNK](http://plnkr.co/edit/KnnWOlvJhoxfQ4mFvBDz?p=preview) where I have a navbar. The goal is to have the 'About' button take the user to the about component. The components are already in the plunk.

I initially wrote more here, but it comes down to the fact that I don't understand why my routing doesn't work (I feel like I set it up correctly):

```
<a routerLink="/home-page" routerLinkActive="active">Home</a>
```

That code doesn't do anything when clicked. My route definitions look like this:

```
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AboutPage } from './about-page.component.ts'
import { HomePage } from './home-page.component.ts'

export const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home-page', component: HomePage },
  { path: 'about-page', component: AboutPage }
];
```

Also, for whatever reason, putting `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in `navbar.components.ts` shows router-outlet as not found and throws. Also, I am 99% percent sure that base href is set up correctly, so probably no need to check that.

In short, how do I make my routes work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** added all **.ts files** into **src folder**

---

**2)** You need to import **RouterModule**  and then use it with **forRoot() method** as shown in **app.routing.ts**

```
import { Routes,RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

---

**3)** Now, you need to import **routing** in **@NgModule's imports metadata**.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule,routing ],
  ...
})
```

---

**4)** Last, added **default route** in **app.routing.ts**

```
export const appRoutes: Routes = [
     {path:'',redirectTo:'home-page',pathMatch: 'full'},
     ...
     ...
   ];
```

---

**Working Demo : http://plnkr.co/edit/mEvR1vU8EEkctNikaNAi?p=preview**

Comment: Thank you! //comment length